# Set value on different html element types with same jQuery function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Using Cordova 2.5.0, I'm using the following function go get all `<input>` elements within an HTML page.

```
function getInput() {
   var formElements = new Object();
   $("form :input").each(function(){
       formElements[this.name] = $(this).val(); //that's this line
   });
   return formElements;
}
```

Actually, I don't *"get"* the elements, but rather the values, as you can see in the fourth line of the snippet.

Now, I'm trying to set the values later on in the application.

```
function insertResults(data) { //data is a json string
    console.log("in insertResults (JS): " + data);
    var jso = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var key in jso) {
        addContentToElement(key, jso[key]);    
    }
}

function addContentToElement(elementname, valuetoset) {
    $(function() {
        $("input[name='" +elementname +"']").val(valuetoset);
    });
}
```

The `console.log()` prints about this: `in insertResults (JS): {"checkbox3":"","textfieldmulti1":"some text","textfield1":"some more text","boxed1":"even more text","checkbox1":"on","checkbox2":"on"}`

And above code works just fine for html textfields. However, if possible, I'd like to set the value for checkboxes et cetera as well, and I kinda hoped `.val(value)` would do the trick, after all, I can retrieve the value of the element as well with `.val()`, even from other elements, like a checkbox. I'd rather not check every element I want to add content to, and according to the element type, use the correct jQuery method to set the value of an element.

Any way or method to achieve this?

(To clarify just a little more:) `addContentToElement("checkbox3", "on");` does not work, although I retrieve `on` from `.val()` from the element, but `addContentToElement("textfield1", "some text")` does. And I know I can do it with `.prop('checked', true)`, or `.attr('checked', true)`, but since I can get the value with `.val()`, why not set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use "val()" for checkboxes and radioboxes to check because they are different from textboxes. they works when you change "checked" attribute to send form data to server, website,..etc. You can use val() only when you want to change value (value attribute).

So if i understand correctly, you want to change checkboxes when "addContentToElement" function get "on" value. I changed your code and you can use code below.

```
function addContentToElement(elementname, valuetoset) {
 $(function() {
     if (valuetoset === "on") {
       $("input[name='" +elementname +"']").attr('checked', true);
     } else {
       $("input[name='" +elementname +"']").val(valuetoset);
     }
 });
}
```

But you should send type to function to find input that is checkbox.

Comment: So the short answer is: "No, you can't, you should handle all different element types (with a switch statement or something)"?